# emit Qt signal from non Qt Thread or ouside Qt main event loop with at 4.5

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4

I'm calling a `emit signal1()` from a non Qt thread.
By non Qt thread I mean not from the GUI Event Loop and not from any QThread run() method or any QThread own event loop.

It is simply a pthread (pthread_create()) that calls a method of a QObject which emits signals.

ex:

```
MyQbject: public QObject
{
...
void emitBunchOfSignals()
{
 emit signal1();
 emit signal2();
 ...
}
...
}
```

the "run" method of my pthread which has a pointer to a MyObject instance (instance that was created within the main Qt GUI thread context NOT the pthread) calls the `emitBunchOfSignals()` methods.

Before Qt 4.5 that was nasty. Now, does Qt 4.5 handle this ? 
Does it call `qApp->PostEvent()` or something so the signal is emitted within the Qt GUI Thread (and thus the slot as well) ?

thanks

Comment: When you call connect, you might explicitly set the type to queued connection.

Comment: In the time it took you to write down this question you could have just opened the code and look for yourself.

Comment: It does not seem straight forward as it used to crash with Qt 3.xx.
I'm familiar with the connect option (directconnection queuedconnection etc) but I thought it worked only between QTreads or between a QThread and the main event loop. Why it used to crash with Qt 3.xx at least was not straight forward to understand by looking at the code. Am I crazy ?

Comment: @Nicolas - Some of the threading code and necessary background make it quite difficult to easily understand what's going on. There's a lot to navigate through, like thread pools, moc, and others.

Answer (score 9):

What you need to make sure is that you use a queued connection to a from threads, as Qt cannot autmatically sense which object that belong to which thread ("thread affinity" is the term used in the documentation). You do this when connecting:

```
connect(src, SIGNAL(signal-signature), dest, SLOT(slot-signature), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

That will result in the signal being put on the event loop of the destination, and the slot being called when its thread is running (i.e. its event loop).

Comment: thanks a lot. 
To make sure I understand what you mean:
Since my emitting QObject does not belong to a QThread nor the main Qt GUI Thread (it belongs to my Corba thread actually), Qt cannot sense the thread affinity. Thus I have to force the connection to QueuedConnection as AutomaticConnection won't work in this specific case.
However when the emitting QObject belongs to a QThread, Qt can sense the thread affinity and a automaticConnection will do the necessary post to the receiver QObject thread's Event loop.