# Slot not receiving Signal in QT application

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I have a bit of a strange situation wherein I have a worker thread doing it's thing and then emitting a signal to callback the GUI thread to close a dialog box. Can someone please explain why this works:

WorkerThread:

```
[Header]
signals:
    void writeComplete(void);

[Source]
void startWorkerThread()
{
    // do some stuff in boost::thread
    emit writeComplete();
}
```

MainWindow subclass:

```
burnDialog = new QProgressDialog("Writing to disc", "", 0, 0);
burnDialog ->setCancelButton(0);
QWidget::connect( discHandler.get(), SIGNAL(writeComplete()), burnDialog, SLOT(close()) );
QWidget::connect( discHandler.get(), SIGNAL(writeComplete()), this, SLOT(close()) );
burnDialog->open();
discHandler->startWorkerThread();
```

but this doesn't:

MainWindow subclass:
    [Header]
    public slots:
        void closeWithDialog(void);

```
[Source]
burnDialog = new QProgressDialog("Writing to disc", "", 0, 0);
QWidget::connect( discHandler.get(), SIGNAL(writeComplete()), this, SLOT(closeWithDialog()) );
burnDialog ->setCancelButton(0);
burnDialog->open();
discHandler->startWorkerThread();

void closeWithDialog()
{
    burnDialog->close();
    close();
}
```

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2074064/894321) solve your problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feeling like a ...  I didn't put `Q_OBJECT` in the header file. I assumed that the fact that the subclass inherited `QMainWindow` that the `Q_OBJECT` interface would also be implicity inherited. But it wasn't... Thanks for the help anyway guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the faulty line in **doesn't work** case:

```
QWidget::connect( discHandler.get(), SIGNAL(writeComplete()), burnDialog,
                  SLOT(closeWithDialog()) );
```

You're assigning a `SLOT` to `burnDialog` instance, that means `closeWithDialog()` method must be of `QProgressDialog` class. `QProgressDialog` don't have any method like that. You should check your console for following message:

```
Object::connect: No such slot QProgressDialog::closeWithDialog()
```

Change above faulty line into following:

```
QWidget::connect( discHandler.get(), SIGNAL(writeComplete()), this,
                  SLOT(closeWithDialog()) );
```

Comment: THanks for catching that muck up. Unfortunately that was just an error of Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V :p. In the actual code, I do have `QWidget::connect( discHandler.get(), SIGNAL(writeComplete()), this, SLOT(closeWithDialog()) );`

Comment: Ohh great.. :) Well, you should `EDIT` the question right away. Also, I hope you checked you're not getting any `connect` failed message in console.